# Why the jsp display the same data multiple time in the same form?

Tags: sql, jstl

I have a jstl table in my jsp with some sql queries, the problem is where I display the table in the browser the table display 1 information but multiple times like 8 rows with the same data.

```
<c:set var="card" value="${listItem.card}" />
<sql:query dataSource="${webchronot2}" var="rs">  
select max(histo_time) as max, min(histo_time) as min from historique WHERE histo_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 7 day) and card like ?
<sql:param value="${card}" />

</sql:query>

<c:forEach var="listItem" items="${rs.rows}">
<td><c:out value="${listItem.min}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${listItem.max}" /></td>
</c:forEach>
```

I work with this code is there something wrong ?

Comment: Why do you think that this is the fault of the presenter and not the fault of the business logic?